# Is 1 Cor. 3:15 talking about the worker being saved or the one being taught?

Tags: teaching

“If any man’s work is burned up, he will suffer loss; but he himself will be saved, yet so as through fire.”
‭‭1 Corinthians‬ ‭3‬:‭15‬ ‭NASB1995‬‬

I understand that the worker will lose reward if he doesn't build upon a person's faith with sound doctrine in sync with God's Spirit, but is the worker the one being addressed here as being saved regardless of their error (but because of their foundation being good) or is this verse addressing the one he is teaching to being saved but as through fire (because the worker's teaching to them is faulty)?

Answer (score 0):

Many may have a misunderstand that 1 Cor 3:15 refers to individual, and infer that a slopy Christian will still be saved just didn't get a reward. This is not 1 Corinthians chapter 3 talking about.

Paul was talking about the leaders of the church, for the church members were dissecting themselves into sects, saying "I follow Paul" and another "I follow Apollos" (vv3:4). Paul said no matter himself, Apollos or another who serviced the church were just co-workers in God's service, and the Corinthians, the church belongs to God.

Paul continued to make an analogy, putting himself as a builder (vv3:10), on the foundation of Jesus Christ (vv3:11), he established a church. There were other builders doing the same service. However, some builders did a good work, that survived God's scrutiny, some did not (vv3:12-15).

> 14 If what has been built survives, **the builder** will receive a reward.
>
> 15 If it is burned up, **the builder** will suffer loss but yet will be saved—even though only as one escaping through the flames. (1 Cor 3:14-15 NIV)

The subject in the whole context is the leaders of the church (builders), not individual member. If the church they built survived, they will receive a reward. If the church was poorly built, then the church will be lost but only the builder survived.

Paul might be cautious to say the poor builders would still be saved. He was cautious for he knew only God was the final judge. He might refer those poor builders were the false teachers, for he continued to say;

> 16 Don’t you know that you yourselves are God’s temple and that God’s Spirit dwells in your midst?
>
> 17 **If anyone destroys God’s temple, God will destroy that person;** for God’s temple is sacred, and you together are that temple. (1 Cor 3:16-17 NIV)

It is undoubtedly to me saying, a poor builder destroy His church, God will make him pay.